# dynamic width of li based on number of lis in a set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set dynamic width to li(s) based on how many li(s) are there in list. For example if there are 18 li(s). Each width should be 100% / 18 = 5.55%. Also what should I do if I would have 3 different sets of ul. I tried to use this.

```
$('.lesson-nav ul li').width( 100 / $(".lesson-nav ul li").length + '%' );
```

For unknown reason: This script gives width 120% while there is only 1 li and 27.55% when there are 18 lis.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MC5PD/ seems to be working correctly here, inspect the `li` it will be `width: 100%` and [with 18](http://jsfiddle.net/MC5PD/1/) i'm seeing `5.55...%`

Comment: Even your answer is working in your fiddle but my coding is disturbing due to some other essence. @nicael solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

> The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter
>   returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former
>   returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px).

So you should use `css(width)`

```
$('.lesson-nav ul li').css("width", 100 / $(".lesson-nav ul li").length + '%' );
```

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot reproduce your 120% problem. To answer your question about "what should I do if I would have 3 different sets of ul", assuming you have 3 different `.lesson-nav`s with lists in them... like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MC5PD/3/)

```
$('.lesson-nav').each( function() {
    $lis = $(this).find('ul li');
    $lis.width( 100 / $lis.length + '%' );
});
```

If you have multiple sets of `ul` within a single `.lesson-nav` then you can modify your selectors a little bit like seen in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MC5PD/4/)

You could also replace the `width()` with `css("width",...)` here if `width()` isn't working for whatever reason.